# Using a type parameter and a pointer to the same type parameter in a function template

Tags: c++, templates

I've written a template function to determine the median of any vector or array of any type that can be sorted with **sort**.  The function and a small test program are below:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace::std;

template <class T, class X>
void median(T vec, size_t size, X& ret)
{
    sort(vec, vec + size);
    size_t mid = size/2;
    ret =  size % 2 == 0 ? (vec[mid] + vec[mid-1]) / 2 : vec[mid];
}

int main()
{
    vector<double> v;
    v.push_back(2); v.push_back(8);
    v.push_back(7); v.push_back(4);
    v.push_back(9);

    double a[5] = {2, 8, 7, 4, 9};

    double r;
    median(v.begin(), v.size(), r);
    cout << r << endl;
    median(a, 5, r);
    cout << r << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the **median** function takes a pointer as an argument, **T vec**.  Also in the argument list is a reference variable **X ret**, which is modified by the function to store the computed median value.

However I don't find this a very elegant solution.  **T vec** will always be a pointer to the same type as **X ret**.  My initial attempts to write **median** had a header like this:

```
 template<class T>
 T median(T *vec, size_t size)
 {
      sort(vec, vec + size);
      size_t mid = size/2;
      return size % 2 == 0 ? (vec[mid] + vec[mid-1]) / 2 : vec[mid];
 }
```

I also tried:

```
 template<class T, class X>
 X median(T vec, size_t size)
 {
      sort(vec, vec + size);
      size_t mid = size/2;
      return size % 2 == 0 ? (vec[mid] + vec[mid-1]) / 2 : vec[mid];
 }
```

I couldn't get either of these to work.  My question is, can anyone show me a working implementation of either of my alternatives?

Thanks for looking!

Comment: It won't help you, but you should make sure your clients know that your median function will, as a side effect, sort their container.

Comment: Side note: `using namespace::std;` is odd, and probably doesn't mean quite what you think it does. Adjusting the whitespace makes it clearer: `using namespace ::std;' but it is far more common to simply write `using namespace std;`

Comment: @zneak - I just realized I actually *don't* want the original container sorted =/ So would I have to work with a copy inside my function?

Comment: yes, you need to work with a copy of the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic approach is to use iterators. To enable this, you can derive the return type from the iterator:

```
template <class I>
typename iterator_traits<I>::value_type median(I start, I finish)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

```
template <class T>
void median( T* vec, size_t size, T& ret )
{
    sort( vec, vec + size );
    size_t mid = size/2;
    ret =  size % 2 == 0 ? ( vec[mid] + vec[mid-1] ) / 2 : vec[mid];
}

template <class T>
void median( vector<T>& vec, T& ret )
{
        median( &*vec.begin(), vec.size(), ret );
}
```

But that's just me.